# Lilypond: Why is the second chord printed below the staff

Tags: lilypond

Small snippet (Simplified example) that should show two chords on top of a staff:

```
someChord = \chords {
  c1
}

\score {
  
  <<
  {
    \someChord
    \someChord
  } 
  {   
    \repeat unfold 2 { r1 }
  } 
  >>

  \layout{}
}
```

However, the second chord is printed below the staff. Why is that?

Tested w/:
GNU LilyPond 2.22.2 (running Guile 2.2)
GNU LilyPond 2.23.7 (running Guile 2.2)

Both give the same output:

[image]

Comment: I can’t tell you exactly why, and it may not be documented. In any case `\chords` is a shorthand for `\new ChordNames \chordmode { … }`, so you are creating two `ChordNames` contexts. I bet if you put both chords in the same `ChordNames` context, they will also show up on the same side of the staff.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work (thanks Ole for the hint!):

```
someChord = \chordmode {
  c1
}

\score {
  
  <<
  \new ChordNames {
    \someChord
    \someChord
  } 
  {   
    \repeat unfold 2 { r1 }
  } 
  >>

  \layout{}
}
```

Result:

[image]

I'm curious why though, because the first `ChordNames` context was ended before the second started....

Comment: If you leave out the staff (so the braces containing `\repeat unfold 2 { r1 }`), two chords in two `ChordNames` contexts still don’t line up horizontally. Seems that Lilypond insists that contexts come under each other, not beside each other. (And a thinkable reason why the second came under the staff could be that since the second `ChordNames` context starts later, Lilypond has decided to put the staff right under the first `ChordNames` before coming around to considering where it can find room for the second; but this is speculation.)